# How do I get a list query field with bdp function (from Rblpapi) from Bloomberg into R?

Tags: r, bloomberg, rblpapi

I am trying to request data from Bloomberg through `Rblpapi::bdp()`.

The query field I want to get contains a list of sponsors (a list of strings) of a specific leveraged loan deal.

`fieldInfo("SPNR_LIST")` reveals the type:

```
fieldInfo("SPNR_LIST")
id                 mnemonic  datatype ftype
SPNR_LIST DX392    SPNR_LIST String   BulkFormat
```

My example:

```
bdp(securities = "BL0739252 Corp", fields = "SPNR_LIST")
```

Example's error:

> Error in bdp_Impl(con, securities, fields, options, overrides,
>   verbose,: Attempt to access value of element 'SPNR_LIST'(type:
>   'SPNR_LIST') as 'String' type.

How can I get the whole list of sponsors of a deal?

P.S. with the `verbose = T` option `bdp` returns:

```
> bdp(securities = "BL0739252 Corp", fields = "SPNR_LIST", verbose = T)

ReferenceDataResponse = {
              securityData[] = {
                  securityData = {
                       security = "BL0739252 Corp"
                       eidData[] = {
                       }
                       fieldExceptions[] = {
                       }
                       sequenceNumber = 0
                       fieldData = {
                            SPNR_LIST[] = {
                                   SPNR_LIST = {
                                         Group Date = 2013-05-28
                                         Sponsor = "Carlyle Group/The"
                            }
                            SPNR_LIST = {
                                         Group Date = 2013-02-04
                                         Sponsor = "Carlyle Group/The"
                            }
                        }
                   }
              }
       }
}
```

> Error in bdp_Impl(con, securities, fields, options, overrides,
>   verbose,: Attempt to access value of element 'SPNR_LIST'(type:
>   'SPNR_LIST') as 'String' type.

Thanks for any help on this. I hope that I described my issue clearly enough.

Comment: Have you tried with `bds`? (bulk fields generally require bds instead of bdp)

Comment: Awesome thanks a lot! Using `bds` did the trick. For anyone later looking at this, use: `bds(security = "BL0739252 Corp", field = "SPNR_LIST")`

Comment: Feel free to put that as an answer in the section below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using bds does the trick: 
`bds(security = "BL0739252 Corp", field = "SPNR_LIST")`

@assylias solved my issue, thanks again mate.